# What is the alternative to deprecated split function

Tags: php

Can some one please help me know how to handle the deprecated function split.
I just don't know PHP that well and will appreciate a correction to my code to stop showing an error.

I am getting an error saying 
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\msacco\sendsms.php on line 84

Line 84 is the one that has the syntax
$aux=split("\r\n",$responsecontent);
On the code here it line 17.

How do i properly replace this split function to stop showing error on page?

The block of code is

```
       else {
               $salida ="POST $uri  HTTP/1.1\r\n";
               $salida.="Host: $host\r\n";
               $salida.="User-Agent: PHP Script\r\n";
               $salida.="Content-Type: text/xml\r\n";
               $salida.="Content-Length: ".strlen($postdata)."\r\n";
               $salida.="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
               $salida.=$postdata;
               fwrite($da, $salida);
               $response = "";
               while (!feof($da))
                       $response.=fgets($da, 128);
               $response=split("\r\n\r\n",$response);
               $header=$response[0];
               $responsecontent=$response[1];
               if(!(strpos($header,"Transfer-Encoding: chunked")===false)){
                       $aux=split("\r\n",$responsecontent);
                       for($i=0;$i<count($aux);$i++)
                               if($i==0 || ($i%2==0))
                                       $aux[$i]="";
                       $responsecontent=implode("",$aux);
               }//if
               return chop($responsecontent);
       }
```

Comment: from the docs: "`split()` is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. `preg_split()` is the suggested alternative to this function. If you don't require the power of regular expressions, it is faster to use `explode()`, which doesn't incur the overhead of the regular expression engine."

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.split.php#refsect1-function.split-notes

Answer (score 1):

You want [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode):

```
$response = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response);
```